# How to intergrate mvc web app into asp.net web app inside one asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Inside .net project - 
We have asp.net web application which is a main application, and for migrating asp pages to mvc pages we create mvc web application inside same project and added mvc web app reference to main asp.net web app.

but when we run the project for some menus which are created in mvc pages it says
**"The view 'ViewName' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:"**

and to solve this --> ***I have added mvc web app "view folder" to asp web app and that resolves the issue.***

**Problem:**
So the problem here is that, I have to maintain the view folder at both the applications, **is there any way to keep the view folder in mvc web app only and use it in asp web app.**

[image]

Comment: There's no need to create a separate subapplication under the main site. Both the old app (that presumably uses aspx pages) and the MVC app can be run under the main site. I'd recommend to simplify your configuration to reflect that.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - Under 1 solution we have 1 aspx web app (older one) and 2 mvc web app (newly created). Can you tell me what configurations I have to change to solve that